Permanova (vegan::adonis2) with two factors but one factor is significant for vegan::betadisper
I really appreciate your help on this.
I have a data matrix of relative abundance of 20 taxa identified at the genus level via 16s.
They belong to 100 human subjects.
Subjects were randomly grouped into 5 treatments (20 subjects per treatment).
Microbiome 16s was measured at 4 timepoints.
So basically data can be organized as follows:
100 subjects, 5 treatment (20 subjects per treatment), 4 timepoints per treatment.
MY QUESTION:
When running betadispers prior to PERMANOVA, I get a significant P-value for the treatment factor, but not for timepoints within treatment.
Should I run a Permanova for every treatment group independently given the fact that treatment factor does not meet the assumption for Permanova?
Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
